# Can a reuse AWS instances algorithm be still useful when switching to payments by usage minutes?

Tags: amazon-ec2

We have the algorithm to reuse AWS EC2 instances for jobs.  This was very useful when the payments were by using time rounded by hours. Now, due to the change in the AWS policy  the payments can be done by time expressed in minutes. At first glance there is no reason to keep the reuse algorithm because a job lasts at least 10 minutes up to many hours.  Are there any suggestions why this algorithm can still be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're running an EC2 instance for less than a minute (which it sounds like you're not) and need per second billing or are using an EBS volume with it, I would say probably not.  See [more details here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html)